# Instruments: Memory Leak vs Allocations

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory, instruments

Reliability of Instruments in the Leak detection. When I'm running Instruments Leak looking for I detected a few leaks that I believe are not, and when I see the Allocation chart I see a memory increase but then decreases, I understand it is released. Therefore, I understand there is a contradiction between Leaks and Allocations.

Does anyone know if I can Leaks are giving a false positive? or is "Allocations?

Comment: the leaks tool seems to do that. especially at the start... theres always a memory leak right at the start. Anyway, I use "build and analyze" in the build menu... its the same as memory leaks tool, but the leaks come up like build warnings, and are specific to your code.

Comment: I also use "Build and Analyze", and don't detect this "leak" that are show in Instruments.